# How can i resolve Constructor not defined error?

Tags: apex, class

I have created class using custom setting. I need to retrieve data from custom setting. I am getting constructor not defined error my error line is options.add(new SelectOption)Please find below code. How can I resolve this error. Please can any one suggest me.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class CustomSettingsController {

    public string ISOCode {get;set;}
    public list<RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c> options_list {get;set;}
    public list<RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c> options_list_Split {get;set;}

     public String selectedIso {get;set;}

     public List<selectOption> isoCodes {
        get {
          List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();

            for (RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c iso : RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c.getAll().values())

            options.add(new SelectOption(iso.Model__c,iso.Name+' - '+iso.Model__c));
            return options;

        }
        set;
      }

     public void getrecords(){

           options_list = new list<RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c>();
           options_list= [SELECT Name,Model__c FROM RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c WHERE Model__c = :ISOCode];


      }
       public void SplitRecords(){

           options_list_Split = new list<RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c>();

          //for (Country_Custom_Setting__c iso : Country_Custom_Setting__c.getAll().values())
           // options.add(new SelectOption(iso.Model__c,iso.Name));
             options_list_Split= [SELECT Name,Model__c FROM RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c WHERE Model__c = :ISOCode];
             //return null;

      }


}
```

Comment: Try this `options.add(new SelectOption(''+iso.Model__c,iso.Name+' - '+iso.Model__c));`

Comment: @Ashwani thanku for quick response I am getting another Error: Invalid bind expression type of String @ another query line this line:options_list_Split...

Comment: Try this then:  options_list= [SELECT Name,Model__c FROM RFLEET_CS01_Grid_Protocol_Lines__c WHERE Model__c = :Integer.valueOf(ISOCode)];

Comment: What data type is the Model field? Surely changing the definition of ISOCode from a String to the correct data type would be a better option

Comment: @Ashwani getting same error can you suggest me what did I worng.

Comment: @BarCotter My all field type is checkbox. Can you retune my code please?

Comment: what value does `Model__c` contains? any example value

Comment: Model is a checkbox?

Comment: @Ashwani model doesn't have any value checked for checkbox..

Comment: @BarCotter Yes  Model is checkbox

Comment: @Nikitha what does the user type in for  ISOCode then?

Answer (score 5):

The [SelectOption constructors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_SelectOption_ctor_2.htm) signature is

```
public SelectOption(String value, String label)
```

Your error may be caused by the `Model__c` field, if it is not a `String` then you will get error you are seeing.

You could convert it to a String in the following way:

```
String.valueOf(iso.Model__c)
```

Be aware that if `Model__c` is null then the above line will result in the String `'null'`